# Create Google Alert on news with multiple keywords

Tags: google-search

I have a set of keywords that I would like to monitor on Google News, using their function (or other free open source solutions) to get Alerts via email.

Google Alert:
[image: Google Alert]

Do you know if there exists such a way to monitor multiple keywords?

The keywords I would like to monitor are around 5000.

Comment: What's the problem with just creating all of the alerts?

Comment: Do you mean manually? If yes, it is because they are quite a lot (like 5000 different search queries). If there exists such a way to put all of them under monitoring with a single action (for instance by using `;` or `&`) that would be much appreciated.